# Sharepoint 2010 Modal Dialog - Opening a dialog within a dialog

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I am using SharePoint 2010 and I have managed to get a list to open within a modal dialog. I am now trying to get another list to open within the same modal dialog when you click a button. (Ideally, close the first dialog then open another)
Here is my modal dialog declaration:

```
function OpenDialog(url)
    {
      var dialogOptions = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
      dialogOptions.url = url // URL of the Page
      dialogOptions.title = 'Dialog Window'
      dialogOptions.allowMaximize= true
      dialogOptions.width = 635; // Width of the Dialog
      dialogOptions.height = 335; // Height of the Dialog
      SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(dialogOptions); // Open the Dialog
    }
    function DialogCallback(){
       SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose(SP.UI.DialogResult.cancel,'Cancelled'); 
       }
```

So I have managed to close the dialog correctly, but I cant seem to get it to open a new one. Ive used www.google.co.uk as an example, I just need it to open in either the same dialog (replacing whats currently there) or close the current dialog and reopen a new one...

```
href="#" onclick="window.frameElement.cancelPopUp(); OpenDialog(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

You forget to option : **dialogReturnValueCallback** in you Option object.

You can pass a function to this parameter. When to Modal is Closed (ok, cancel ...) this function will be executed.

Do somthing like this :

```
function OpenDialog(url)
{
  var dialogOptions = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
  dialogOptions.url = url // URL of the Page
  dialogOptions.title = 'Dialog Window'
  dialogOptions.allowMaximize= true
  dialogOptions.width = 635; // Width of the Dialog
  dialogOptions.height = 335; // Height of the Dialog
  dialogOptions.dialogReturnValueCallback = Function.createDelegate(null,DialogCallback )

  SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(dialogOptions); // Open the Dialog
}
function DialogCallback(result, target) {
   if (result == SP.UI.DialogResult.OK) {
        //Close the Modal with the function : SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose(SP.UI.DialogResult.OK, returnValue);

        //Here Your First Modal is close normaly, open Your New Modal Dialog

   }else if (result == SP.UI.DialogResult.cancel){
        //Close the modal with the function : SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose(SP.UI.DialogResult.cancel,returnValue); 
   } else{
        //The user have closed the modal with the cross 
   }
}
```

So in your Parent page, jsute call :

```
OpenDialog(url);
```

In your First Modal, to close normaly the Modal :

```
SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose(SP.UI.DialogResult.OK, "a value to return ...");
```

And then the DialogCallback function will be executed, and then you can open you new Modal